# injectivity. identity map of a ring to its tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $B$ be an $A$-algebra, $f: B \rightarrow B \otimes_{A} B$ is defined by $f(b)=b\otimes 1$.

Is $f$ injective?
I know the definition of tensor product and started from representing as

$(b,1)=\sum n((x+y,z)-(x,z)-(y,z)) +\dots $

but can't do anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $g\circ f$ is the identity for some map $g: B\otimes_A B \to B$, then $f$ is injective for formal reasons.  Namely, if $f(b_1) = f(b_2)$, then $b_1 = g(f(b_1)) = g(f(b_2)) = b_2$.  The fact that $B$ is an $A$-algebra means that you have a good candidate for $g$.